# Excel VBA cannot determine when SQL Server stored procedure has finished executing

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, stored-procedures, vba

I am executing a stored procedure in SQL Server from Excel VBA. The stored procedure takes several minutes to run, but the VBA code originally continued to run and displays a "done" message, even when the stored procedure was still executing.

To remedy this problem, I added a loop to check if the connection to SQL Server is executing something, but for some reason, I am getting stuck in the loop and never reaching the end message.

Here is what I have written:

```
Dim cn As Object
Dim startTime As Variant, endTime As Date

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
cn.Open = ...connection string stuff to open...

    cn.Execute "stored_procedure", , adAsyncExecute

    Do While (cn.State And adStateExecuting) = adStateExecuting           
        DoEvents
    Loop 

cn.Close
Set cn = Nothing

MsgBox "Execution completed"
```

For some reason, when I print the connection state inside of the "Do while" loop, it only says 1 (1 = connection is open, instead of 4 = executing). Yet the loop is never exited!! Am I missing something here?

Comment: If you want to wait until it is finished executing why are you running it async?

Comment: You seem to be using late-binding for your ADODB, which is cool and all, but then I don't see where you define the `adStateExecuting` constant. Does your code work if you change it to `Do While (cn.State And 4) = 4` ?

Comment: @SeanLange Perhaps OP wants to notify the user inside the loop that it's still working?

Comment: @JNevill could be but the loop there sure make it look like they want to wait until it is finished processing to move on.

Comment: I'm trying to give OP the benefit of the doubt, but I also completely agree with you. I'll just sit up here on my fence.